# Align Stars in Table including Boarder using HTML

Tags: html-table, border, cellspacing

I am creating a table only with HTML but would like to add spacing between my skills and stars so that the starts alingns with each other?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Management⭐⭐⭐⭐</td><td>OSHE Act⭐⭐⭐</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accounting⭐⭐⭐</td><td>Marketing⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want it like this but incliding the border showed above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGdvx.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and post text information as text, not images.  For best results use the snippet tool `<>` when you are editing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.